# How to provide a custom path for webpack configuration

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm working from a directory that has symlinks to my source files

```
workingDirectory
  - webpack.config.js
  src (sylmink to ../myproject/src
```

So, when I provide `[absolute-resource-path]` to devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate, the source map contains the resolved path

```
/path/to/myproject/src/File.vue
```

Or if I provide `[resource-path]` if prefixes with webpack://

```
webpack:///./src/File.vue
```

How do I get it to use the symlink path?

```
/path/to/workingDirectory/src/File.vue
```

webpack.config.js
Note, I have a custom resolveWorkspace function that provides the correct path for the files.

```
'use strict'
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

function resolveWorkspace(dir) {
    //This will resolve the symlink paths
    // return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
    //Instead, use the PWD which contains the symlink paths
    return process.env.PWD +'/'+ dir;
}

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, '.'),
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: {
        app: resolveWorkspace('resources/assets/js/app.js')
    },
    output: {
        path: resolveWorkspace('public/js/'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: '[absolute-resource-path]',
        devtoolFallbackModuleFilenameTemplate: '[absolute-resource-path]?[hash]'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
            '@': resolveWorkspace('resources'),
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                include: [resolveWorkspace('resources')]
            }
        ]
    },
    target: 'node',
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    node: {
        // prevent webpack from injecting useless setImmediate polyfill because Vue
        // source contains it (although only uses it if it's native).
        setImmediate: false,
        // prevent webpack from injecting mocks to Node native modules
        // that does not make sense for the client
        dgram: 'empty',
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty',
        child_process: 'empty'
    }
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
    //Inline the source map for testing.
    module.exports.devtool = 'inline-source-map';
}
```

Comment: if i got you right!! use `path.resolve(/*../your/path*/)` instead of `'../your/path'`

Comment: That isn't valid for the devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate directive. Where would I put that?

Comment: can you post your `webpack.config.js` file?

Comment: @AhmedM.Kamal config file added ^

Comment: for `resolveWorkspace` function you can replace `process.env.PWD +'/'+ dir` with `path.join(process.cwd(), dir)` and for `devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate` you can track [this issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3377)